# How to get all data from Tables in SQL with similar name in R

Tags: mysql, sql, r

i am new to R and i want to merge multiple Tables from my SQL DB with R.

The problem is not to merge them, but to get the query. I have a lot of tables with similar name(just numbers at the end are different) in the DB.

Now i want the data in these tables to work with them in R. I already tried to import these table names from a .txt document and this works. But i can´t use the function `dbGetQuery(connection, "SELECT * FROM...")`

right with with method because it allows only the real table name and no variable with multiple names.

Over that i tried

```
dbGetQuery(connection, 
"SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '..._%'")
```

but this gives just table names and not the data in there.

I hope anyone can understand my problem.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Also note that "merging" the tables is something of a meaningless concept unless you tell us the table structure and your logic for merging.

Comment: I am using MySQL.
I want to merge the tables because the are from two different measuring devices with the same columns. And i just want one table with all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import all tables to list and merge in R. (Included `LIMIT 100` for test purposes)

```
tables <- dbGetQuery(con, {"
  SELECT concat(TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',TABLE_NAME) tab
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
  WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'pattern%'"})$tab


data <- 
  lapply(tables, function(table){
    dbGetQuery(con, sprintf({"
      SELECT * 
      FROM %s
      LIMIT 100
      "}, table)
    )
})

library(magrittr);library(dplyr)
data %<>% bind_rows()
```

Or if one wants to keep it in MySQL, and is sure that tables have same structure, function below returns query which union all tables matching `pattern`:

```
union_all_mysql <- function(pattern){
  tables <- dbGetQuery(con, sprintf({"
  SELECT concat(TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',TABLE_NAME) tab
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%s'"}, pattern)
  )$tab

  query <- 
    lapply(tables, function(table) 
      sprintf("select * from %s", table) ) %>%
    unlist


  paste(query,collapse=" union ")

}


union_all_mysql("users_%")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate the SQL query using `paste` or `sprintf` function:

```
dbGetQuery(connection, sprintf("select * from %s", table_name))
```

By executing this for each `table_name` obtained from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables` query, you will have tables' data in R.

Comment: I think this is far from the requirements of the question.

Comment: `because it allows only the real table name and no variable with multiple names.` – the answer code doesn't have real table names. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this in R, I would do it in Workbench directly.  First create a new table to hold the merged results:

```
CREATE TABLE AllData (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    col1 varchar(55),            -- replace with your actual column types
    col2 int,
    ...
 )
```

Then just do the following `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO AllData (col1, col2, col3, ..., colN)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ..., colN
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ..., colN
FROM table2
UNION ALL
...
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ..., colN
FROM tableM
```

The above assumes M tables each having the same N columns, but you will have to fill in the blanks yourself.